# Copy an atrribute value from one attribute to an inner string within the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have an `<A>` tag, in which I need to copy the value of the `HREF` attribute to an inner string within the `REL` attribute. To be specific:

```
<a href="XX-some-link-XX" class="cloud-zoom-gallery small" 
rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallimage: 'XX-this-is-where-i-want-to-copy-that-link-XX'">
<img />
</a>
```

I've been able to partly achieve this by doing the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".small").each(function() {
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var a = jQuery(this).attr('rel', src);
});
});
```

But that removes the other data within the `REL` attribute (e.g `useZoom`).

So my question is - how to copy an attr value and paste it within a specific sting in the value of another attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad your `rel` isn't a well-formed JSON object, or you could use `JSON.parse()` to do the work.

This is probably cumbersome, but it's pretty generalizable.

```
$(function() {
    var $jq = $("a:eq(0)");
    var j = relParser($jq.attr("rel"));
    j["smallimage"] = $jq.attr("href");
    $jq.attr("rel",relBuilder(j));
    alert(relBuilder(j));
})

function relBuilder(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (attr in obj) {
        arr.push(attr+": '"+obj[attr]+"'");
    }
    return arr.join(", ");
}
function relParser(str) {
    var arr = str.split(",");
    var obj = {}; 
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var tmp = arr[i].split(":");
        obj[tmp[0].trim()] = tmp[1].trim();
    }
    return obj;
}
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(rel.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+):/g, '"$1":'))` would format it properly

Comment: I... *think* I like that better. (No, really. I always prefer built-in methods, even if they're a bit harder on the eyes.) Now if there was only a built-in JSON serializer to do the other half of the work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the example to appending at the end:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".small").each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
       $this.attr('rel', $this.attr('rel') + " " + $this.attr('src'));
   });
});
```

if you will need to more specific - you need to format value as you need. Like a simple strings in javascript.

Feel free to get the attribute value as a string an modify it before putting to the `rel` attribute.

Comment: can you been a little mor clear? im sorry, im new to this so im not really sure how to do what your suggesting. can you show me a full example that is exactly what i need? thanks so much for answering either way

Comment: I mean that you will need to get the attribute value first, change as a string and only then put back. There is no function to append values to attribute. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

What Samich is saying is something like this (I won't tested but may works):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".small").each(function() {
        var src = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        var rel = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        result = rel + src;
        var a = jQuery(this).attr('rel', result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't added `smallimage:` as an attribute in your `a`s yet, you could do this

**html**

```
<a href="XX-some-link-XX" class="cloud-zoom-gallery small" 
rel="useZoom: 'zoom1'">
<img />
</a>
```

**js**

```
$('.small').each(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel'); 
    $(this).attr("rel", rel + ", smallimage: '" + a + "'");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/a9BRz/

*You will need to use the* inspect element *on the result panel to see how it works*